# nginx serves both port 80 and 443 but always returns HTTP 404 on port 80

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx `v1.22.1` on my Raspberry Pi 4 (based on Debian Bookworm). nginx returns HTTP 404 `Not Found` for all requests via HTTP/port `80`:

[image]

However, everything works nicely via HTTPS/port `443`.

Here's my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And this is my configured site `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myraspi.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /hello {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 'Here I am!';
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myraspi.fritz.box.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certificates/myraspi.fritz.box.pem;

    location /world {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 'Here I am!';
    }
}
```

I can successfully call `HTTPS GET myraspi/world`, but not `HTTP GET myraspi/hello`. However, since the error page contains the nginx footer, it seems to be an nginx config issue.

I've already checked whether nginx listens to both ports - which is the case:

```bash
myuser@myraspi:/etc/nginx $ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972636/nginx: mast
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1972636/nginx: mast

myuser@myraspi:/etc/nginx $ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972636/nginx: mast
```

The config check `sudo nginx -t` also succeeds:

```bash
myuser@myraspi:/etc/nginx $ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

The error log `/var/log/nginx/error.log` contains no errors and within the access log `/var/log/nginx/access.log`, I see the incoming request:

```
<<my IPv6 IP address>> - - [30/Mar/2024:13:35:03 +0100] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 125 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0"
```

Any ideas about what might be the problem?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following line to `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myraspi.conf` to add IPv6 support:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /hello {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 'Here I am!';
    }
}
```